# User authentication in angular js and java from Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs

I have to authenticate the user on my login page from my database in mysql using angular JS and java(Controller, Service, DAO, DTO etc.)
Using spring hence expecting spring security
 Please help

Also please help in Session building and Role based Routing of user

Comment: Is this AngularJS or Angular? You have tagged angular in your question but talking about AngularJS.

Comment: Please provide more details like what you have tried and where you are facing issue etc in the question itself .. that will be helpful to people who tries to answer your question.

Comment: @AJT_82 I am working on Angular JS

Comment: @JithinScaria I am facing problem in picking the user inputs and sending them to the java controller using Angular JS